# Cite the article title (from a book or website) in the text

Tags: titles, citations

How do I cite both the author and article title of a website or book in the text?

Here is an example reference:
Smith, A. (2012). *How to cite an article title*. Available: https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/ask. Last accessed 8th April 2012.

Instead of just (Smith, 2012)? The answer may be obvious and I know what it might be but for the benefit of clarity, and keeping this question answerable, I have omitted my suggestion.

Comment: Are you using any particular style manual?

Comment: What do you mean? (I'm using Harvard referencing style)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Harvard you shouldn't do this. If you need to clarify an ambiguity between authors with the same last name or two articles by an author in the same year you should use (Smith A., 2012)/(Smith B., 2012) or (Smith, 2012a)/(Smith, 2012b).

This is the case for Harvard AGPS I'm not sure for the other varieties but I assume it's not significantly different if at all. You could mention the article name within your text but the citations should only contain minimal detail.